# How to check when HTML fetched by AJAX is totally parsed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, animation

I have a site where I fetch additional HTML with AJAX (and jQuery). I parse this HTML with [jQuery.parseHTML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) and add the parsed HTML into my site with the function [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/). I also use [animations](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) for displaying the new content.

Now I have some display problems which happen, when the parsed HTML is big. When I reload the same site everything is fine (maybe because the HTML is cached by the Browser). So I think the problem may be that the HTML was not totally parsed and prerendered by the browser. How can I check, when the fetched HTML is totally parsed and ready for rendering? (Note: I append the new HTML in way, that it is not directly visible to the user. Just the animation slides the new content in).

The function [ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) does not seem to work. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Why not use a semaphore? Each ajax call will increment it and each success or error callback will decrement it, when it is 0, all calls are done and then show the animation. `ready` won't work it does not know there are ajax calls.

Comment: Did you try this in multiple browsers? Also, are making the new node `display: none` or the wrapper that you are appending to is hidden?

Comment: @Mohsen: I tried it with firefox and chromium. In both browsers I have the same problem. The new content is in a for user non visible div which will be slided in (``display:none`` is not set for this div)

Comment: parseHTML is synchronous call. It won't return until the Html is parsed. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: My best guess is that you put your calls in `requestAnimationFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

With ajax you can append .success or .done see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
}
})
.done(function( data ) {
if ( console && console.log ) {
console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
}
});
```

the done(function(data){} will contain all data and you can do what you want with it. It is called as soon as it has finished loading

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not, what I am looking for... I already received the new data, my problem is to check when the fetched HTML is totally parsed and prerendered by the browser... Something like the ready() function of jQuery which does not work for me.

Comment: You could maybe work with the onReadyStateChange? But it will change state when you fetch data not when it's rendered.http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp